# Solve 1-D coupled differential equations analytically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coupling

I'm currently going through an article where I came across these two 1-D coupled differential equations.

$$\frac{dA}{dz} = a_1B(z)e^{-i\beta z} $$
$$\frac{dB}{dz} = a_2A(z)e^{i\beta z} $$

with these three conditions
$$ \frac{d}{dz}(|A(z)|^2 +|B(z)|^2)=0 $$
$$ a_1 =-a_2^* $$
$$ B(0)=B_0, A(0)=0 $$
The article then skips all steps and arrived at these two solutions, subject to the three conditions,
$$ A(z)=B_0\frac{2a_1e^{-i\beta z/2}}{\sqrt{4|a_1|^2+\beta^2}}sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4|a_1|^2+\beta^2}z \right) $$
$$ B(z)=B_0e^{i\beta z/2}\left[cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4|a_1|^2+\beta^2}z\right)-i\frac{\beta^2}{\sqrt{4|a_1|^2+\beta^2}}sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4|a_1|^2+\beta^2}z\right)\right] $$

Any idea on how the author arrived at these two expressions? I tried integrating by parts but ended up with $A'(z)$ and $\int{A(z)}$ terms that I can't get rid of. The author also made no mention of trial solutions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Differentiate, for example, second equation then substitute $A'$ using the first one. You will get second order equation containing only $B$ and its derivatives

Comment: Just a small change to what @Vasili suggested: multiply first the second equation by $e^{-i\beta z}$. Otherwise the differentiation will contain a term with $A$, which you will need to write in terms of $dB/dz$. It's the same result, but less likely to make mistakes.

Comment: @Vasili : Not quite.  Differentiating the second equation gives a second order DE in $B$ depending on $A$ and $A'$, only the second of which can be substituted.

Comment: @EricTowers You can write $A$ in terms of $dB/dz$

Comment: @Andrei : I agree, but this is not what Vasili wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the first equation through by $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z}$ and differentiate.  (We do the multiplication so that $B(z)$ doesn't appear multiplied by another expression depending on $z$ so we don't have to use the product rule and end up with terms depending on $B$ and $B'$.)
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left(
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z} \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}z} \right) &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left( a_1 B(z) \right)  \\
\mathrm{i} \beta \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z} A'(z) + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z} A''(z) &= a_1 B'(z)  \\
    &= a_1 a_2 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z} A(z) 
\end{align*}
so
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z} \left( A''(z) + \mathrm{i} \beta A'(z) - a_1 a_2A(z) \right) = 0  \text{.}  $$
Since $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta z}$ is never zero (standard example of [Picard's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem)), we must have
$$  A''(z) + \mathrm{i} \beta A'(z) - a_1 a_2 A(z) = 0  \text{.}  $$
Using the side condition between $a_1$ and $a_2$,
\begin{align*}
  A''(z) + \mathrm{i} \beta A'(z) &{}+ a_1 a_1^* A(z) = 0  \text{,}\\
  A''(z) + \mathrm{i} \beta A'(z) &{}+ |a_1|^2 A(z) = 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
This is a second order linear ([autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)), although we do not use this fact) ODE with constant coefficients, so we solve the [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)),
$$  r^2 + \mathrm{i} \beta r + |a_1|^2 = 0  \text{,}  $$
obtaining
\begin{align*}
  r &= \frac{-\mathrm{i} \beta \pm \sqrt{-\beta^2 - 4|a_1|^2}}{2}  \\
  &= \frac{-\mathrm{i}}{2} \left( \beta \pm \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2} \right)  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
From this,
\begin{align*}
A(z) = C_1 \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-\mathrm{i}}{2} \left( \beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2} \right)z} + C_2 \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-\mathrm{i}}{2} \left( \beta - \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2} \right)z}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Taking $z = 0$, the initial condition gives $C_1 + C_2 = 0$.  Substituting this $A$ into the $\mathrm{d}B/\mathrm{d}z$ equation and simplifying a bit, we obtain
\begin{align*}
B(z) = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2 a_1} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-\mathrm{i}z}{2}\left(-\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2} \right)} 
\left(
C_1 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}) z}
\left(-\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2} \right)
- C_2 \left( \beta  + \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2} \right)
\right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Taking $z=0$, substituting into the left of $B(0) = B_0$, using $C_2 = -C_1$, and simplifying, we obtain
$$  C_1 = \frac{-\mathrm{i} a_1 B_0}{\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}}  \text{.}  $$

Substituting for $C_1$ and $C_2$, and simplifying, we obtain
\begin{align*}
A(z) &= \frac{\mathrm{i} a_1 B_0}{\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}} 
\left( 
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}\right)z/2} 
\right)
\left( 
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}\right)z} - 1 
\right)  \\
B(z) &= \frac{B_0}{2\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}}
\left( 
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\left(-\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}\right)z/2} 
\right)
\left( 
\left( 1 - \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}\right)z}
\right) \beta
+ \left(
1 + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(\sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}\right)z}
\right) \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4|a_1|^2}
\right)
\end{align*}
(With a great deal of algebraic effort, we can show that the $z$ rate of change of the sum of the squared moduli of $A$ and $B$ is zero, showing that the first side condition is redundant.)  Then use $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = \cos(\theta) + \mathrm{i} \sin(\theta)$ and simplify (using one or two trig identities) and you get the answer you have.

Comment: Modulo typo's and transcription errors, the above may even be correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution in the article was missing a minus sign but this shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** One can eliminate one of the functions via differentiation and substitution to produce an o.d.e. in, say, $A$ alone. Differentiating the equation for $A'$ gives
$$
A'' = a_1 e^{-i \beta z} (B' - i \beta B).
$$
Substituting for $B'$ using the second equation (in particular using that $a_1 a_2 = a_1(-\overline{a_1}) = -|a_1|^2$) and for $B$ using the first equation gives a second-order, linear, constant-coefficient equation,
$$A'' + i \beta A' + |a_1|^2 A = 0 ,$$
in $A$ alone.

> **Additional hint** We can solve this equation in the usual way: Substitute the ansatz $A(z) := \exp \lambda z,$ which yields the characteristic equation for $\lambda$: $$\lambda^2 + i \beta \lambda + |a_1|^2 = 0.$$

Can you take it from here?